# Зависание потока

Tags: c#, многопоточность, асинхронность, task

Использую стороннюю библиотеку, в которой есть асинхронная функция. Это функция при некоторых условиях может работать некорректно и зависать "навечно".
Пытался прерывать задачу с помощью токенов отмены, а также помещал функцию в отдельный поток и пытался "убивать" его Abort'ом. Ничего не помогает.

Разработчик библиотеки признает проблему, но решение к сожалению предложить никакое не может. А создавать альтернативу этой функции я не могу. Что же мне делать?)) Можно конечно игнорировать эти зависания и создавать новые потоки до тех пор, пока все не пройдет гладко. Но это ведь утечки, на сколько я понимаю. Не очень нравится такое.

Есть предположение, что можно создать отдельный процесс, который бы содержал только эту функцию. Тогда даже при зависании функции вроде бы не должно возникнуть проблем с завершением этого процесса. Пойдет ли такой вариант и какие возможные негативные последствия могут возникнуть при таком решении?

Собственно функция открывает в браузере вкладку с авторизацией, затем эту функция ждет, когда я авторизуюсь в ней. И только после этого работа продолжается. Однако если я проигнорирую авторизацию и закрою вкладку или браузер, то функция так и останется в ожидании, потому что, как я понял, она не в состоянии перехватить событие закрывающейся вкладки в браузере.

Вот и функция:

```
private SheetsService GetSheetsService()
{
    UserCredential credential;
    using (var stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        string credPath = "google-token";
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            new string[] { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
    }

    return new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    });
}
```

Comment: вы говорите про возможную абстрактную проблему кода в вашем представлении, который писал другой разработчик и воспроизведение которой вами не определено. Это максимально неконкретно. Приведите код, выясните причину зависаний, напишите пример для воспроизведения проблемы, тогда поговорим, а с тем, что вы указали, советовать нечего - есть миллион причин по которым асинхронная функция может зависнуть

Comment: "Alert" - имелся в виду `Abort`? По идее, это должно работать (хоть и опасно, и не рекомендуется). | Кроме отдельного процесса, можно использовать домены приложений. | Эта асинхронная функция она IO-bound или CPU-bound?

Comment: @tym32167, поправил

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да, аборт. Перепутал просто. И да, он не работает.
Функция IO-bound. Добавил пример функции

Comment: @your_mind вы это все случайно не в UI-потоке пытаетесь провернуть?

Comment: Если вы это в UI потоке делаете, то у вас дедлок. Почему бы не ожидать результат асинхронной функции асинхронно?

Comment: Вот тут еще какое-то решение есть: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609700/4340086

Comment: @tym32167, сначала делал в UI потоке, потом пробовал запускать в другом потоке и запускать асинхронно. результат все равно один - функция зависает навечно. разница лишь в том, что если запускать в UI потоке, то получается дедлок, а если асинхронно, то - утечка. ни то, ни то меня не устраивает

Comment: @PavelMayorov, там вроде бы немного другая ситуация. там просто при вызове этой функции не открывалась вкладка в браузере, если я правильно понял. но все равно попробую

Comment: Использование `Result` прям пахнет дедлоком. Почему вы не сделаете вашу функцию асинхронной?

Comment: @VladD, и чем же это поможет? поток так и останется висеть

Comment: @your_mind: А вы пробовали? Есть хорошие шансы, что дедлок вызван именно использованием `.Result`.

Comment: @VladD, да, я пробовал. что вы подразумеваете под дедлоком? имеете ввиду, что мой UI поток блокируется из-за `.Rusult` асинхронной функции, из-за чего дальнейшая работа процесса невозможна? если так, ты вы правы. я действительно ловил дедлок из-за этого. но проблема то не в этом. проблема как раз в том, что та асинхронная функция зависает. и не важно жду я результата асинхронно или нет. даже если избегать дедлока с использованием асинхронного вызова, проблема останется. т.е. функция так и останется висеть навечно, не завершившись. а меня это не устраивает.

Comment: @your_mind: Ну если функция даже при её использовании без `Wait()` и `.Result` зависает, то, мне кажется, нет смысла использовать библиотеку.